.gradlew signingReport Build Failed
trying to get SHA1 fingerprint certificate , however when im trying to run the .gradlew signingReport ,getting below error
PS C:\Users\tawde\AndroidStudioProjects\Test> ./gradlew signingReport
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'Test'.


Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.6.1.
Required by:
project : > com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.6.1
> No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.6.1 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.7' but:
- Variant 'apiElements' declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
- Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
- Other compatible attribute:
- Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7')
- Variant 'javadocElements' declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
- Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
- Other compatible attributes:
- Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
- Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
- Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7')
- Variant 'runtimeElements' declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
- Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
- Other compatible attribute:
- Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7')
- Variant 'sourcesElements' declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
- Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
- Other compatible attributes:
- Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
- Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
- Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7')
Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2.
Required by:
project : > com.google.gms.google-services:com.google.gms.google-services.gradle.plugin:4.4.2
> No matching variant of com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.7' but:
- Variant 'apiElements' declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
- Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
- Other compatible attribute:
- Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7')
- Variant 'javadocElements' declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
- Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
- Other compatible attributes:
- Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
- Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
- Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7')
- Variant 'runtimeElements' declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
- Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
- Other compatible attribute:
- Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7')
- Variant 'sourcesElements' declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
- Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
- Other compatible attributes:
- Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
- Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
- Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7')


Try:


Review the variant matching algorithm at https://docs.gradle.org/8.7/userguide/variant_attributes.html#sec:abm_algorithm.
No matching variant errors are explained in more detail at https://docs.gradle.org/8.7/userguide/variant_model.html#sub:variant-no-match.
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

trying to et sha1 certificate using .gradlew signingReport , however getting error build failed
